# .net mvc 5 view helper function returning boolean

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a few static functions to be used in my view that compare a number of model attributes and the logged in user and then returns a boolean. The view then uses the boolean in an @if to conditionally display partial views.

I thought about writing an @Html helper method, but it looks like those only return strings. Currently I have the checks hard coded in the view, but I would like to extract them so that I can unit test them. What is the best way to go about doing this with .net MVC 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending WebViewPage would be a good solution if I needed helper functions to be available in all of my views, but since I only need them in one view, I figured out how to get the helper function working.

Helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
    public static class TransactionHelper
    {
        public static bool ShowAcceptDecline(TransactionStatus status, String transactionUserId, String currentUserId)
        {
            return status == TransactionStatus.PendingAcceptance && transactionUserId == currentUserId;
        }
    }
}
```

And then the key thing that I didn't know was to add @using in the view:

```
@using MyProject.Helpers
@model MyProject.Models.Transaction

@if (TransactionHelper.ShowAcceptDecline(Model.Status, Model.UserId, User.Identity.GetUserId()))
{
    @Html.Partial("_Pending", Model)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension for **System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage** and call it in a view like `@this.CompareModelIdAndUserID();`